# Is there a bitwise trick to increase only zero to one?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

In C++, is it possible to achieve the following with a bitwise trick?

```
(i == 0) ? 1 : i
```

Assume that `i` is an unsigned 32-bit integer.

EDIT: This is out of curiosity. The goal is not to optimize and clearly not to improve readability.

Comment: You could do `i += !i;` or `i |= !i;`, but is it really any better?

Comment: @chris Very nice! You should post this as an answer, I'd gladly upvote it.

Comment: What's the benefit of using a bitwise trick rather than the clear and obvious code in your question? Is this expression a measured performance bottleneck for your application?

Comment: Here is a trick to make your code more readable to humans: `if (i == 0) i = 1;`

Comment: While I'm not very strong at maths and modular arithmetic neither, I don't suspect one can make such a function without relying on conditionals.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That has very different semantics from the code in the question, which doesn't modify `i`.

Comment: Why would you want a trick for something that can be trivially done without a trick?!

Comment: I would use `i = max(1u, i)` which is not a bit trick (or maybe it is, I've seen branch-less implementation of `max` for `uint32_t` ^_^)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: By "trick" OP probably means branchless and thus more performant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until I see real results that say otherwise, I believe your code is much clearer and just as fast, but either of these accomplish the same thing without the conditional:

```
i + !i
```

Or

```
i | !i
```

If `i` is 0, `!i` is 1. Combining 0 with 1 through addition or bitwise OR always gives 1. If `i` is non-zero, `!i` is 0. Combining a non-zero value with 0 through addition or bitwise OR always gives that value. Thus, the result is 1 if `i` is 0 and `i` if not.

Again, I will be surprised if either of these actually turn out to be better for the compiler.

Comment: I would be surprised as well. :) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

On computers with two's complement representation of negative numbers, you can use this formula:

```
(!(n & -2)) | n
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/y1hKPq)

Explanation: Bit pattern for -2 has ones in all bit positions except the least significant one. Therefore, the expression `n & -2` will be zero only when `n` is equal to zero or one. The `!` will make one from zero and zero from any other number. Hence, zero or one will be OR-ed with one, while any other number will remain intact.

Comment: But if you use `!`, how is this better than using what chris proposed in his comment (`i += !i`)?

Comment: @JoSo It's not - [I just posted a comment for Chris about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099410/is-there-a-bitwise-trick-to-increase-only-zero-to-one/25099463#comment39057360_25099410). I was making my demo while he posted his comment, so I didn't see his solution.